# Need to Show Tencent weibo icon in UIActivitycontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

avc.excludedActivityTypes =  @[
    UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
    UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
   ,
];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I removed UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo.

The following icon only presenting

(mail,message).

Still not showing tencent weiboo,qq,qzone. (all the application are installed in my device. But no luck  :(

(Checked ios device with 8.1 version) Please help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, ]; [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Because you just excluded all of these options.

You **want** them, therefore you do **not want** to *exclude* them. Get rid of the excluded types and only exclude what you **don't want** :-)

Comment: Finally i removed UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo...but still not coming. So If i want to show mean, what i want to add?

Comment: You also must be logged in in the settings app.

Comment: Still no luck.. I tried UIDocumentinteractioncontroller...It will open all the application. expect tencent weibo..any way thanks for your valuable feedback .